# Firebase security rule for a subscription service

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

We're looking to build a Subscription Service on top of Firebase but we're having some issues working out the Security Rules.

When a User is authenticated, we want to be able to allow them to either pay for a subscription manually or setup recurring payments. As far as I can tell, this can only be accomplished with [Custom Authenticated User](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html) on a small script on a server but I was hoping to avoid this if possible.

Does anyone have any examples or ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: For clarification, do you not have a backend other than firebase?

Comment: I don't believe you want to manage subscription with firebase only, it's too risky

Comment: @DylanWatt - We're still planning out the application structure.  We CAN have a backend other than Firebase but I was hoping to keep as much user data in Firebase as possible.

Comment: @YannChabot - Can you elaborate on that? Is Firebase "too risky as a whole" or "too risky for subscription management"?

Comment: Firebase alone does not include any server side logic, everything has to be managed by the client. At some point you'll need to store data like "user has paid us." With only firebase, that user will post up the flag indicating he paid, which is not great, because he can post that up whether or not it's actually true, without server side validation. You should treat Firebase like a database. You still need another layer on the backend to manage that database.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. This is Day 2 of my playing around with Firebase/Security rules, so I'm still trying to get my bearings. I wasn't sure if I was missing something because many of the examples they provide are completely devoid of server side logic.

I really appreciate the insight!